# Find files with autopsy

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

I had an Ubuntu 14 machine. A couple of days I installed Ubuntu 18 on this machine.

I'm trying to recover some files from the previous installation. I'm using autopsy.

I think I'm doing something wrong. I search for the keyword require that I had in my files but nothing is found:

[image]

[image]

I added the disk as **/dev/sda** which is the same I'm working on.
If I search for a filename in my current installation it doesn't find a match.

I want to find the file contents in the disk if they are still there.

**Edit**

I just found this error on the terminal after clicking on the "search" button.

```
double free or corruption (fasttop)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After searching on Internet it seems like an implementation error of TSK/Autopsy and not a missing depencency or library.

Comment: Did you go through all the ingest steps and allow it time to complete the processing? With a large disk on an older machine it can take quite a while. Try searching for something you know to be present on the new image to test your ability to search; troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Looks like you didn't adhere to the advice that is written in bold on every OS installer ever: **Installing a new operating system will delete all your data. Chances of recovery are minimal!** Unless you have backups, it's probably safe to assume that the data is gone.